# How to distinguish my appointment from delegator appointment in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm writing C# addin, and I have a problem with appointments. Let's say that I'm delegated user, so I have two calendars in my outlook, on is mine default calendar, and one calendar of my delegator. When I click on my calendar or on delegator calendar, appointment is opened. My question is how to determine from which calendar it was opened? In matter of fact, even an information that it is not appointment from mine calendar would be enough for me...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

You can get the appointment's mailbox name by:

```
    (((Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem).Parent //this returns "Calendar" folder
       as Outlook.MAPIFolder).Parent                            //now point to this appointment's root mailbox   
       as Outlook.MAPIFolder).Name;                             //this returns "Mailbox - UserName"
```